How Would "Chemical Weapons" be expressed in Latin?
Post graduation I attended an interview with the now-defunct ICI corporation. It was a two-day affair with a dinner, in the evening, attended by the candidates and the interviewers. During this, in polite conversation, it was asked, en passant, how would we feel about working on chemical weapons. I commented that this would be tantamount to selling one's soul to the Devil.
To what extent this contributed to my not getting the job can only be guessed at.
Translating this into Latin throws up some predictable problems: a chemical weapon? A chemical weapon is a poison e.g. chlorine, mustard gas, nerve agents inside a propulsion/distribution system. Therefore, how about "arma venenorum"--"weapons of poisons"?
Is this a good guess?

I would go with simply arma chemica.
In addition to chemical weapons there are biological weapons and radiological weapons, so working with words related to poison might lead the reader astray.
As, to the best of my knowledge, such distinctions were not clearly made in the ancient world, it is best to go with a modern technical term.
If you want to speak of poison instead of chemistry, I suggest arma venenosa.
But beware of possible miscommunication:
If you speak of poisonous weapons, I for one would not think that you are referring specifically to chemical weapons.
Clear communication and adhering to classical terminology are often incompatible when it comes to describing modern phenomena.
I don't know whether all weapons you could call poisonous are chemical weapons.
Some biological and radiological weapons could plausibly be called poisonous.
My understanding is that chemical weapons are weapons of massive destruction, so an individual poisoned dart would not be a chemical weapon but would clearly strike me as a poisonous one.
I'm no expert on the classification, but the message stands:
Use established terminology or beware confusion.

What is your understanding of chemical weapons vs biological weapons? "Chemical weapon" in my experience is typically used to describe poisons/toxins/irritants, and "biological weapon" to describe bacterial or viral agents designed to spread contagion.

@RLH My understanding is similar but not very refined. Perhaps poison is a better fit than I thought, but I still wouldn't parse "poisonous weapons" to mean "chemical weapons" without being explicitly told so. I would be inclined to count some radiological and biological weapons as poisons as well, but I'm not expert on the classification.

I edited a bit, adding one good example: A poisoned dart is to me clearly a poisonous weapon but does not appear to be a chemical weapon. The latter category is only for weapons of mass destruction, as far as I can tell.

@Joonas llmavirta: The guess was "weapons of poison"; an attempt to indicate that, not only pernicious, but completely different from conventional weapons. Also, brevity; imagining a Roman centurion ordering his men to deploy "the poisons".  Fritz Haber, he of the Haber process, described the use of chemicals as "a higher form of killing". (A sweet guy.) At the Battle of Tannenberg (August 1914) flamethrowers were deployed, for the first time. Is a flamethrower a chemical weapon--you wouldn't want to be on the receiving end--any more than from mustard gas, phosgene and all the other delights?

@tony If Wikipedia is to be trusted, chemical weapons are only used on a larger scale. Therefore a poisoned dart or a flamethrower do not qualify. I'm sure there's a gray area around the definition, and the experts to guide you through it might not be here.
